# Why isn't the OAS3 nullable attribute recognized by the Newtonsoft Schema Validator?

Tags: json.net, swagger, jsonschema, openapi

My API is documented using Swagger OAS3. I have a property defined using YAML as:

```
LoanAmount:
 type: number
 nullable: true
```

The resulting JSON I can export from swagger looks like:

```
  "LoanAmount": {
    "type": "number",
    "nullable": true
  },
```

When I test validating using [jsonschemavalidator](https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/) with the schema as:

```
   {
      "title": "A JSON Schema for OpenAPI 3.0.",
      "id": "http://openapis.org/v3/schema.json#",   "$schema": 
      "http://json-schema.org/",   "type": "object",
      "properties": {
      "LoanAmount": {
      "type": "number",
      "nullable": true}
       }
    }
```

and input as:

```
{
  "LoanAmount" : null
}
```

The validation fails with

> "Invalid type. Expected Number but got Null"

I can make this work by using:

```
"LoanAmount": {
"type": ["number","null"]
}
```

However, I cannot figure out how to define it that way using OAS3 YAML. My goal is not to have to maintain a separate schema outside of swagger hub to satisfy my nullable requirements on the many fields in my API.

A swagger docs [page](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/keywords/) describes that OAS3 "uses an extended subset of JSON Schema Specification Wright Draft 00 (aka Draft 5) to describe the data formats..."

The Json.Net Schema documentation says that "Supports 100% of JSON Schema Draft 6 and has backwards compatibility with older versions"

My assumption is that the OAS3 nullable attribute is one of the extended subset features and not part of any JSON schema draft, but I'm looking for confirmation of this before I move on.

Comment: Confirmed. `nullable` is not a JSON Schema keyword.

Answer (score 0):

OAS3 uses a subset superset of JSON Schema keywords.

See https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.2.md#data-types

> Primitive data types in the OAS are based on the types supported by
>   the JSON Schema Specification Wright Draft 00. Note that integer as a
>   type is also supported and is defined as a JSON number without a
>   fraction or exponent part. null is not supported as a type (see
>   nullable for an alternative solution). Models are defined using the
>   Schema Object, which is an extended subset of JSON Schema
>   Specification Wright Draft 00.

Confirmation.
There is work being done to allow the full use of JSON Schema in future versions of OAS!

Comment: This work is now complete as of OpenAPI 3.1, which allows full JSON Schema draft 2020-12